# Parse HTML in javascript without loading all resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I know there has been many question around this but I did not find any answer to my specific case (which should not be that specific after all).

I am build a html mobile app for multi platform using cordova, angularjs and ionic. My app is getting web pages from a server that I do not own and I need to extract some data from those pages.

I have found many ways but not satisfactory to me.

1. jQuery : I manage to parse the HTML successfully but unfortunately parsing my html page triggers the loading of the resources such as images which I don't want at all. I just want to extract string from the html page and certainly not load all the images.
2. create a virtual dom element with innerHTML like this

   ```
       var el = document.createElement( 'div' );
       el.innerHTML = MyHtmlPage;
   ```

   same issue like JQuery, the resources like image are loaded too.
3. Using a DomParser like this

   var el = new DOMParser().parseFromString(string, 'text/html');

This is not supported by [all platform browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

I wish someone can help me find a decent solution, I may otherwise use regexp but I hate those.

Comment: I think images and such are only loaded when you add the HTML to the DOM. Did you do that using the jQuery solution? Can you show the code of that one?

Comment: @GolezTrol I originally thought that too, but apparently it does! [(See Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/uaksqdpc/)

Comment: Wow!  That's crazy.  Do you have a server running for this application?  I'm thinking a proxy to download the page for you may be a solution.

Comment: Try DOMParser with fallback to ActiveX.

Comment: @Ninsly Good find! This surprises me, actually.

Comment: the app is supposed to access the user's house alarm server so I have no way to access them or proxy them.